# How can I remove the VS 2015 status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

What is the magic potion for removing the status bar in `VS 2015`?

In my environment it has the following options:

> **Encoding:**  Unicode (UTF-8) - BOM
>   **Content type:** CSharp
>   **Classification:** None

Thank you.

Comment: This is not the _status bar_ but an additional information injected by a plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sven was seeing this additional information above the status bar:

[image: Extra status bar above the one displayed by Visual Studio]

This information is added by the [Extensibility Tools 2015 plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab39a092-1343-46e2-b0f1-6a3f91155aa6). The settings to turn off what is called the *Editor Margin*
can be found under *Options* > *Extensibility Tools* > *General*:

[image: Extensibility Tools general options]

Setting the value to `False` and restarting Visual Studio 2015 hides this information.

Comment: Great. You might consider upvoting the answer ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough rep points to vote.  Once I do I'll come back and make a valid vote.

Answer (score 9):

Click on `Tools > Options > Environment > General` and uncheck the `Show status bar` option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't do it.  I'm referring to the status bar above THAT status bar in my environment.  When I clear the check box above as you suggest the IDE stops displaying the line, column and character numbers.  What I'd like to remove is the status bar  (perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology) which displays the encoding type, the content type and the classification. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have sufficient reputation points yet to be able to do that, but it's a bar at the bottom of the editor with the elements I detailed in my original post.  The visual layout is:  editor on top; 2nd is the encoding bar that I'd like to remove; third is the bottom dock bar (right now I have the Package Manager Console there); on the bottom is the status bar.

Comment: Upload the screen shot somewhere and add the url here.

Comment: Thanks, might not be the bar OP wanted to have removed but the one i wanted to have removed :)